# Best way to industrialize raspberry pi 3b+

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, industrial

I work on a Raspberry project, the purpose of this project is to use a Raspberry to control an industrial machine.

My customer would like to produce several hundred Raspberry.

I have an custom Raspbian image and I would like to know how "flash" my image on this several Raspberry in an industrial way.

> For the moment, the customer wants to use an **Raspberry Pi3b+**.

Do you have any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Kinda off-topic question for here. But, we are using one of [these](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Systor-Multiple-microSD-Memory-Duplicator/dp/B003VJSSXS) SD card duplicators if that helps.